# Is double-spending a problem to all blockchain or just to crypto-currency blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I am learning more about all the different consensus mechanisms used in current blockchain technology. From what I read, people seem to be claiming that double-spending for all blockchains. It is easy to understand that it is the case for crypto-currency. But is it still a problem for blockchain designed not for cryptocurrency, such as IoT, logistic?

This brings me to another angle that if double-spending is really a problem pertaining to the mechanism design aspect. E.g., POW is one way of solving the double-spending problem. But other consensus mechanisms may not focus on the double-spending problem.

Any help and comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Double spending is just an example for byzantine behavior, which includes explicit malicious actions by participants in the protocol.

PoW does not solve double spending per se. Rather, as a probabilistic approach mitigates the chances for a successful double spend.

With blockchains (usually) one seeks for tolerating byzantine faults, which is only possible to a certain extent. In case of PoW you deal with a *computational threshold adversary (51% attack)*, whereas with classical BFT protocols as a consensus layer alternative you deal with a *threshold adversary model (3f+1*). Alternatively, when using PoS you deal with a *stake threshold adversary* where you're again bound by resources.

It always depends on your use-case and what you are trying to solve with your system. Therefore, there is no *one-to-rule-them-all* solution and depending on your applications requirements certain consensus layer solutions might be more suitable than others.

(*Note:* also other system properties as latency/throughput etc. play an important role)

So to answer you question, if you generalise and consider byzantine faults, then yes, it is also a problem for other consensus protocols. Otherwise, if you don't mind that your system may rewrite history as it's not mission critical, then you can ask yourself: why even a blockchain?